# Determine read capacity unit for an Amazon DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-serverless, dynamodb-queries

How to determine read capacity unit for a table when get query returns different number of items in each api call(eg:- one get query returns 50 items , another get query returns 500 items from the same table )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all about averages.

If your average fluctuates significantly over some time period e.g. over the course of a day, you can use autoscaling.

If your table doesn't see enough requests to have a stable average throughput, you probably don't need to worry too much. Give yourself some breathing room but also keep in mind that DynamoDB allows bursting so you don't need to be too exact over time.

Also consider how your data is distributed and the relative temperatures of your data in your table. Read and write throughput gets spread across all partitions equally, meaning cold partitions get an equal read throughput as hot partitions. It is always the goal to structure your data so that it is evenly distributed and equal temperature.